# How can I view solr spellcheck dictionary

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am testing Solr Cloud and I don't receive spellcheck (DirectSolrSpellChecker, IndexBasedSpellChecker) results. I want to debug why it is happening.

So, how can I see Solr/Solr Cloud spellcheck dictionary? How can I "look" inside it to see why I don't receive results?

Comment: What spellchecker are you using? They use different types of data - one uses the index directly, one builds its own dictionary, etc.

Comment: I have tried DirectSolrSpellChecker and IndexBasedSpellChecker and I assume that it is building dictionary using data in index (collection)

Comment: Only IndexBasedSpellChecker will build anything - the DirectSolrSpellChecker uses content from your existing index. The `spellcheckIndexDir` setting will define where the parallel index built by IndexBasedSpellChecker will be stored.

Comment: But what is a field that DirectSolrSpellChecker (if in my case it set to `<str name="field">_text_</str>`)? What is this `_text_` filed?

Comment: It's a field named `_text_` in your regular index. It's included in the example schema, which is why it's used as an example name.

Comment: I see, thanks. With some manipulations of config I have achieved that spellcheck is working somehow. But are there any alternative spellcheck solutions for Solr if functionality of standard spellcheckers will not enough?

Comment: Then you might be looking at something like the suggest module or check whether the commercial offerings around Solr might have what you need -
 but first - define what you actually need and are looking for.